# Star Mark as Favorite Books, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application where the user is shown a list of books with a star next to each (this part I've got down). I want my user to be able to click one or more stars on the page in order to save one or more books as a favourite.

I'm looking to see if I'm on the right track/if I should be doing this a different way.

I also know that I need JavaScript in the views and I'm still working that part out.

Models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :users, through: :favorites
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :books, through: :favourites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller

```
class FavoriteController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    current_user.favorites.create(:book_id => params[:book_id])
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

Routes

```
match "favorites_controller/:book_id" => "favorites#create", :as => :favourite
```

Comment: Check this link http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/25/5-star-ratings-with-rails/

Answer (score 0):

This looks reasonable. There is the possibility here of creating duplicate records. You may want to add something like this to avoid record duplication:

`class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :book_id, scope: :user_id
end`

Depending on what version of Rails you are using, you may have trouble with the match route – somewhere around Rails 4 these  began requiring a qualifying array of method types using via.

So for a recent version of Rails you'd need to specify the method eg get 'favourite/:book_id' => 'favorites#create', as: :favourite, or match 'favourite/:book_id' => 'favorites#create', as: :favourite, via: [:get, :post]

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  I'm also a little confused as to where the javascript function goes. would favorite also have its own show.html.erb file in view where i put that code? (and are there any other pieces that i am missing?)

Comment: Carly –– Depending on how you are making the XHR request, you could remove the render layout: false line, and instead return javascript using in a show.js.erb or show.js.haml file, you could return JSON and handle it with javascript, or you could use javascript to listen for ajax events that the Rails ujs driver provides, eg ajax:success (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax). js.erb or listening for ajax:success etc events may be the simplest and most effective way of handling what might just entail adding a class to your favourite icon or something like that in this scenario.